# Is http://mydomain.com/me@mail.com safe to use as URL?

Tags: url, rfc3986

I consider to setup a server to deal with URLs including email address such as

```
http://mydomain.com/me@mail.com
```

According to RFC  3986, I userstand @ is reserved on authority part = //mydomain.com/,
but unreserved on path part /......., 
so currently I assume it's ok to use email address on pass.

Having said that, I still not sure if it is safe to use like
http://mydomain.com/me@mail.com
on production.

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: `http://` is not part of an email address...

Comment: Well, I'm not talking about email address itself, but URL 'including'  email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine—your interpretation of the RFC is correct, and there's no "risk" (in terms of browsers doing the wrong thing) for using an `@` in the URI portion.